# Can I install Laravel Homestead with a 32-bit Vagrant box?

Tags: windows, laravel, vagrant, virtualbox, homestead

My processor, a Pentium T3200, doesn't support Visualization Technology. I keep on getting this error with I run `vagrant up`:

```
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...

Timed out while waiting for the machine to boot. This means that
Vagrant was unable to communicate with the guest machine within
the configured ("config.vm.boot_timeout" value) time period.

If you look above, you should be able to see the error(s) that
Vagrant had when attempting to connect to the machine. These errors
are usually good hints as to what may be wrong.

If you're using a custom box, make sure that networking is properly
working and you're able to connect to the machine. It is a common
problem that networking isn't setup properly in these boxes.
Verify that authentication configurations are also setup properly,
as well.

If the box appears to be booting properly, you may want to increase
the timeout ("config.vm.boot_timeout") value.
```

I am using Virtualbox on Windows 10.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: you can check [here](https://gist.github.com/noeldiaz/0f9a2583a41579878764) how to build a 32 bit box

Comment: Oh. I didn't saw that link. Thanks, though!

Answer (score 0):

I've tried all possible solutions to run a default Laravel's homestead, but it's impossible to run on an old 32-bit CPU.

To fix it, I created a new homestead 32-bit, using the last version of Laravel settler and Ubuntu 14.04 i386 (32-bit) and posted it on [GitHub](https://github.com/rmff/laravel-homestead-32bit).

I hope this helps people starting with Laravel and homestead.

Comment: Thanks! I will check it.